# Is there a LaTeX-like font for my other documents?

Tags: fonts, latex

Every time I open a document written in LaTeX, I can tell just based on the font. I want to know if there is a Latex-like font out there I can use for my other documents.

I realize that latex's way of doing fonts is pretty complicated (and takes into account stuff like kerning and... other font-related vocabulary that I don't understand.) But I would like to be able to download a nice little font file and install it on my computer and type text in Office or set my system fonts to look like they were typeset in latex.

Is this possible? Where can I find something like this? (google searching "latex fonts" and variants simply gives me Latex's different font options or descriptions on how latex handles fonts.)

I am using Ubuntu (and OpenOffice), but I also use Windows boxes. That is to say, Windows-only or Linux-only solutions are fine with me!

Comment: Related question on [tex.se]: [What is the .ttf font for default LaTeX font?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98476)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) or some other word processor-like front end to LaTeX ([Scientific Workplace](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/swp.html~mainFrame), maybe).

I mean, not what you asked for, but you didn't say *why* you wanted this. Is it the interface? Or something else?

BTW-- That default TeX font is called [Computer Modern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern), which might help you in your search. And in the wikipedia link I find

- [Computer Modern typeface in TrueType format](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/) and [OpenType](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/otf/).
- [Computer Modern Unicode fonts](http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/) X11 licensed

and others which are probably just what you need.

Answer (score 3):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern) about the Computer Modern typeface has a bunch of links to Type 1 and OpenType formats.

You probably don't need to install all the variations. Just the 12-point size should work for most applications. The smaller sizes are hinted to make them more legible, but you probably won't need those.

Most of the links on the Wikipedia page point to the CTAN archives, so you may have to dig around through some directories to get to the TTF and OTF font files.

Edit: A friend of mine once pointed out that New Century Schoolbook set at about 110% of its normal width bears a resemblance to Computer Modern.